# How can I neutralise H2 gas without burning it?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, safety, hydrogen, gas-phase-chemistry

I was thinking of maybe making it bubble into a solution containing something that would react with H2 yielding either a dissolved substance or a precipitate from the reaction.

---

Maybe a solution with a small amount of H2O2 in it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*neutralise*"? In chemistry this usually suggests an acid-base reaction, or decomposition of dangerous/hazardous substances.

Comment: @andselisk It is to avoid the dangerous accumulation of H2 gas (produced as a byproduct of a reaction) into the room where I carry out the reaction. I'd like to avoid explosion/fire hazards.

Comment: If it would react, it could as well react dangerously  If you are not going to burn it, you may to mix it with excess of air or nitrogen, keeping hydrogen safely below explosive concentration.

Comment: H2O2 won't help at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. If it's going to necessitate complex catalytic devices I might just as well extract it from the building in a safe way (for instance, as Poutnik says, diluting it before extraction). I was just thinking maybe there's a simple reaction which makes I can transform it simply bubbling it through a liquid and therewith incorporating hydrogen atoms back into a safe molecule (like water, except without burning it not to risk detonation).

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and to try to learn more about chemistry), why is it that H2O2 + H2 doesn't yield 2 H20? Would it work if my H2O2 solution was hot enough (all the while keeping it sufficiently diluted to avoid problems with it)? Does H2O2 non-catalytically decompose into H2O and O2? and if so would heating the solution to the required temperature to make it react with H2 significantly speed up that decomposition? (I can see the risks involved with releasing concentrated O2 around H2)

Comment: Could H2O2 + H2 ⤑ 2 H2O at a temperature at which H2O2 would not release O2 if I used a catalyst in the solution, as say ionised iron or copper? (wild guesses knowing they catalyse some oxidation reactions)

Comment: Or maybe it would then also catalyse the release of Oxygen? If so, would there then maybe a catalyst that would strongly favour the reaction between H2 and H2O2 vs the decomposition of H2O2?

Comment: You really need to contact your local ES&H/Safety person and follow their instructions. If you have no such person, stop and do not proceed.

Comment: @Veritas Jon was merely trying to help.  No one is doubting your education level or accomplishments, but performing something potentially dangerous without knowing exactly what you are doing could turn out to be a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @jonsca Knowledge and knowledge only can help people ignorant on a topic, not suggesting they reach out to luxury resources (given the proportion of people who have access to an ES&H/Safety person the comment was outright delusional if not advocating for the exclusive practice of chemistry to the tiny group of people who do, which would severely impair technological development & innovation/evolution). You can give people knowledge and warn them at the same time, that's perfectly reasonable, but telling them to "stop and not proceed" without giving them any knowledge is all but helping others.

Answer (score 2):

Many nuclear power plants use so-called "passive autocatalytic recombiners" for the catalytic oxidization of hydrogen that could be released into the containment in the event of severe accidents. (Note that the affected units of the Fukushima-Daiichi plant did not have such equipment.) The catalytically active materials, typically platinum and/or palladium, are doted on carriers, preferably designed as catalyst plates orientated vertically to support the flow.